# Problems with HWIOAuthBundle first example

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I am fighting against HWIOAuthBundle.
I am trying to make it work with twitter Oauth but I am not sure I am on the right road and I apologize from now if this question may appear trivial.

I am Following the few instructions reported on the doc.

I have this configuration:

```
config.yml

hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: secured_area;
    resource_owners:
      twitter:
        type: twitter
        client_id:      <consumer_key>
        client_secret:  <consumer-secret>



routing.yml

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /login




security.yml
    firewalls:
       ...
        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    twitter:            "/login/check-twitter"
                login_path:        /login
                use_forward:       false
                failure_path:      /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

In the oauth_user_provider I've understand I can use one of the three default implementations reported in the doc page https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-configuring_the_security_layer.md

If I try to access to a page covered from this configurations I receive :

*ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58: The service "hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils" has a dependency on a non-existent service "hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.secured_area;".*

Please is there somebody can tell me what this error is caused from ? Is the service I've specified in oauth_user_provider a bad one and I've misunderstood the doc about the 3 default implementations of services implementating  the OAuthAwareUserProviderInterface ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hell it was a typo. It's in config.yml, "firewall_name: secured_area;".
I've loosed half afternoon for a damned ";"

@moderators : please feel free to delete this question if you think this  is a zero community contributive question/answer.